# Dividing all columns in dataframe by column in different dataframe using unique identifier of both dfs

Tags: database, r, merge, transform, match

Basically what I need to perform is to transform my country variables into per capita terms, i.e. divide all values by the country's population.

So I have `df`:

```
country <- c("A","B","C","D")
income <- c(10,20,30,40)
cars <- c(100,200,300,400)
df <- data.frame(country,income,cars)
```

And I want to divide all columns by `dfpop$pop`

```
pop <- c(1,2,3,4)

dfpop <- data.frame(country,pop)
```

any ideas?

Comment: Without some [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) data and code, its hard to say how best to do this.  Please edit your question accordingly using something like `dput(head(Y))`.  However, my guess would be you should add the column of population to data.frame `y` and proceed from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you only have one observation per country there's not need of aggregating data, just a  division using `df/variable`

Taking into account merge pointed out above by @lselzer you can try:

```
 DF <- merge(df, dfpop)
 DF[,-c(1,4)]/DF[,4]
  income cars
1     10  100
2     10  100
3     10  100
4     10  100
```

But also without using `merge`:

```
df[,-1]/pop
  income cars
1     10  100
2     10  100
3     10  100
4     10  100
```

The advantage of using `merge` is the matching of country names, this will ensure that you're dividing each variable of country `A` by the population of country `A`. The second approach does not ensures the matching of country variables, so you have to take care using this approach.